# How to make picture box randomly change its content

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

Hello ladies and gentleman,

I am a teacher for kids in the kindergarten.
I've decided to create a program in visual basic which would teach young  kids colour names in english.
Although, my knowledge in programming is nothing very great.

Here is what I want to do

1. Button is clicked and the game begins.
2. New button appears.
3. Label changes its text to one of the colour names.
4. Picture box changes its content to random colour and continues to change every second.
5. If they click on a button when picture in picture box is equal to label text colour name they get one point!

I was wondering if anyone could help me out on this one.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you havn't already I would suggest you look at a Winforms tutorial and learn the basics. Something along the lines of [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/vbNet.html). Once you've done this you shouldn't have any trouble doing what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to create a list of all of the colors from which you want the application to randomly choose.  Something like this would work:

```
Dim colors() As Color = {Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green}
```

Then, you can sort the array into a random order, like this:

```
Dim r As New Random()
Dim randomColors() As Color = colors.OrderBy(Function(x) r.Next()).ToArray()
```

Then you can just show them in that order.  To show the first one, you could do something like this:

```
PictureBox1.BackColor = randomColors(0)
Label1.Text = randomColors(0).Name
```